# Find the continued fraction for $\sqrt{k^2+k},$ where $k$ is a natural number

Tags: number-theory

> Find the continued fraction for $\sqrt{k^2+k},$ where $k$ is a natural number.

I know the algorithm how to find it for a specific number, let's say $\sqrt5,$ but any idea and any understanding how it works for this, despite the fact I saw some examples for $\sqrt n,$ but still can't specific my solution

Comment: Well, have you tried it? What is the first step, given then $k^2<k^2+k<(k+1)^2?$

Comment: You can also try the first few values of $k$ and look for a pattern thatn can help you with the general case.

Comment: Greg's comment is exactly on point.  Just *look at some actual examples*.  Have you really not considered that? The continued fraction of $\sqrt{k^2+k}$ at $k = 1$ is $[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots]$, at $k=2$ is $[2,2,4,2,4,2,4,\ldots]$, at $k=3$ is $[3,2,6,2,6,2,6,\ldots]$, at $k=4$ is $[4,2,8,2,8,2,8,\ldots]$, and at $k=5$ is $[5,2,10,2,10,2,10,\ldots]$. The pattern from looking at data is completely obvious. Now you know what to aim to prove.

Comment: Since you referred to **the** continued fraction, I am inferring (perhaps wrongly) that you are looking for the (unique) **simple** continued fraction, where all of the numerators in the continued fraction are required to equal $~1.~$ I strongly suspect that there is no closed form for the simple continued fraction of $\displaystyle ~\sqrt{k(k+1)},~$ since there is no closed form for the simple continued fraction $\displaystyle ~\sqrt{k},~$ where $~k~$ is a square free positive integer.  See also the comment that I left, following the answer of F. Wright.

Comment: @user2661923 it is unusual to think that the failure of $\sqrt{k}$ for all squarefree $k \geq 1$ to have a closed form should mean $\sqrt{k^2+k}$ for all $k \geq 1$ can't have a closed form! Why should the difficulty of a general problem mean special cases must be difficult too? See my previous comment. And think about $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^k$, which for general $k > 1$ has no closed form but famously does have a nice closed form when $k = 2$.  Or think about power series, which in general have no closed form but special cases like geometric series do.

Comment: @KCd I am not saying that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{k^2 + k}~$, expressed as a continued fraction, **can not** have its indices $~[a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots]~$ expressible as a closed form, but rather that **I would be surprised** if there was such a closed form.  My surprise stems from my manually calculating the indices, for upwards of $~10~$ such $~[a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots]~$ sequences.  My intuition has trouble grasping how the significance that the square free positive integer $~n~$ is expressible as $~k(k+1)~$ would make a difference.  So, this could easily be a limitation of my intuition.

Comment: I agree that in advance it's not clear what to expect for $\sqrt{k^2+k}$, but trying the first several examples reveals a pattern, whether or not $k$ is squarefree. It's not an issue of intuition, but of seeing if examples reveal anything interesting. You wrote that you look at 10 examples. Did you mean 10 numbers of the form $\sqrt{k^2+k}$, or 10 numbers of the form $\sqrt{k}$? When I looked at 5 examples of $\sqrt{k^2+k}$ I saw a consistent pattern in their (simple) continued fractions.

Comment: @KCd I meant 10 numbers of the form $~\displaystyle \sqrt{k} ~: ~k ~$ is square free.  Before today, it never occurred to me that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{k(k+1)}~$ would *have a pattern*.  Further, nothing in my *very moderate* survey of the literature ever suggested such a thing.  Regardless of whether your *pattern* is expressible in closed form, I encourage you to post your analysis as an answer (or *partial answer*) to the question, assuming that you are referring to the indices $~[a_0;a_1, a_2, \cdots]~$ that represent the **simple** continued fraction (i.e. all numerators equal to $~1$).

Comment: @user2661923 many square roots have patterns in their simple continued fractions. In the table of continued fractions of $\sqrt{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq 100$ (and $k$ not a perfect square) on the page https://planetmath.org/tableofcontinuedfractionsofsqrtnfor1n102, there are expansions with 2 terms before repeating: $\sqrt{2} = [1,2,2,2,\ldots]$, $\sqrt{5} = [2,4,4,4,\ldots]$, $\sqrt{10} = [3,6,6,6,\ldots]$, $\sqrt{17} = [4,8,8,8,\ldots]$, $\sqrt{26} = [5,10,10,10,\ldots]$, and by this point it's natural to expect $\sqrt{n^2+1} = [n,2n,2n,2n,\ldots]$. Seeing that, it's not hard to prove.

Comment: @KCd In effect, you are asserting that if $~n~$ is expressible as $~k(k+1),~$ then the corresponding sequence $~[a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots]~$ has a *period* of $~1.$  I definitely think that your *discovery* deserves to be posted as an answer.  If possible, your answer might also consider the converse question: if the corresponding sequence $~[a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots]~$ has a period of $~1,~$ does this imply that then, $~n~$ is expressible as $~k(k+1)$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll convert some comments above into an answer.

You wrote that you can work out continued fractions for specific square roots like $\sqrt{5}$. Armed with such knowledge, you simply need to *work out some actual examples* and the answer for the general case will then be quite clear, which you then sit down and prove with the confidence it should be correct.

Here are some initial examples. The continued fraction of $\sqrt{k^2+k}$ at $k=1$ is $[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots]$,
at $k=2$ is $[2,2,4,2,4,2,4,\ldots]$, at
$k=3$ is $[3,2,6,2,6,2,6,\ldots]$, at $k=4$ is $[4,2,8,2,8,2,8,\ldots]$, and
at $k=5$ is $[5,2,10,2,10,2,10,\ldots]$. The pattern from looking at such data is completely obvious. Now you know what to aim to prove, so go ahead and prove it.

This is not the kind of stuff you just guess without actually looking at examples. But after you work out several examples, it's easy to guess what the pattern should be.

In the table of continued fractions of $\sqrt{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq 100$ (and $k$ not a perfect square) on the page https://planetmath.org/tableofcontinuedfractionsofsqrtnfor1n102, there are expansions that have $2$ terms before repeating: $\sqrt{2} = [1,2,2,2,\ldots]$, $\sqrt{5} = [2,4,4,4,\ldots]$, $\sqrt{10} = [3,6,6,6,\ldots]$, $\sqrt{17} = [4,8,8,8,\ldots]$, and $\sqrt{26} = [5,10,10,10,\ldots]$. By this point it's natural to guess that $\sqrt{n^2+1} = [n,2n,2n,2n,\ldots]$. Once you see that, it's not hard to prove the general formula.  I did this when I was learning about continued fractions, and once I figured that out I looked at $\sqrt{n^2-1}$, $\sqrt{n^2+2}$, and $\sqrt{n^2-2}$: in each case there was an obvious pattern from looking at 5 or 6 examples and once I knew what was worth proving, the proofs themselves were straightforward. When I moved on to $\sqrt{n^2+3}$ and $\sqrt{n^2-3}$, there was no longer a common pattern in all cases, so I stopped.

The main lesson here is not to overlook the stage of working out examples before feeling you just don't know what to do.

Comment: ,Thank you so much for your explanations, I really have a very vague idea of ​​how to prove or solve certain types of tasks and it just drives me into a stupor where I don’t understand where to start. So this lesson was extremely useful for me .

Answer (score -2):

For continued fraction we have
$$
\sqrt{x}=1+\frac{x-1}{1+\sqrt{x}}
$$
$$
=1+ \frac{x-1}{2 + \frac{x-1}{2+\frac{x-1}{2+\frac{x-1}{...}}}}
$$
$$
\sqrt{k^2 +k}=k\sqrt{k+1}
$$
$$
=k[1+ \frac{k}{2 + \frac{k}{2+\frac{k}{2+\frac{k}{...}}}}
]
$$

Comment: How does $\sqrt{k^2+k}=k\sqrt{k+1}$?

Comment: Besides the question raised by the comment of qianqian07, your posting has an additional difficulty.  The OP (i.e. original poster) referred to **the** continued fraction.  This suggests (perhaps wrongly) that the OP is looking for **the** simple continued fraction, which is unique.  This means that all of the numerators have to equal $1$.  See also, the comment that I left following the original posting.

Comment: @user2661923,You're right,I meant this.Sorry for the complications and not clear question.At the moment, I am extremely superficially versed in the topic on which I asked the question. In addition, it adds to the complexity that I am trying to cope with three languages: one is where I study, the second is my native language and, finally, English, which I am looking for information and help.

Comment: @user2661923,In any case, thank You so much for your clarifications and comments, this is really an invaluable help for me.